# Why am I obtaining this syntax error when I try to save a WSO2 ESB API having multiple URI query parameters?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have the following problem trying to insert multiple request query parameter into the URI of a REST API.

I have the following situation. Using an URL with a single query parameter (**process_phase_id={process_phase_id}**) it works fine, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/enutrifood/bylocation" name="ENutriFoodByLocation" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{localizationId}/messages?process_phase_id={process_phase_id}">
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
```

But if I have multiple query parameter divided by the **&** symbol, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/enutrifood/bylocation" name="ENutriFoodByLocation" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{localizationId}/messages?process_phase_id={process_phase_id}&q2={v2}">
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
    ...............................................................
```

As you can see now the **resource** have 2 parameters:

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{localizationId}/messages?process_phase_id={process_phase_id}&q2={v2}">
```

Now if I save my API I am obtaining this syntax error message:

[image]

Why? What could be the problem? What am I missing? Have I maybe to escape in some way the **&** character? How can I fix this problem and use multiple query parameter in my API?

Answer (score 2):

As this is an XML configuration file, you need to escape the `&` to `&amp;`.

In XML the `&` indicates the start of an XML entity (which is terminated by a `;`). So to have an actual `&` in your document, you need to escape it.

As to the error, in your document, the parser see `q2` as the name of the entity, but stops parsing at the `=` and concludes that you have a syntax error, as it didn't see a `;` to end the entity.